# Suitelet Request Giving Bad Request 400

Tags: javascript, suitescript2.0

I have a suitelet that works most of the time but undert a single condition throws a Bad Request 400 error.

The following doesn't work

```
https://[REDACTED]-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?
script=[REDACTED2]
&deploy=1
&bookingid=1769444
&components=this
&operations=geteligiblecomponents
```

This one does work

```
https://[REDACTED]-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?
script=[REDACTED2]
&deploy=1
&operations=getuserdetails
```

Both of the redacted parts are the same in both requests. I've also broken in onto separate lines for readability. I don't understand what would be causing a Bad Request here

I swapped out my components params as it was sensitive information. It was 7000+ characters long

Comment: What says the error message inside the response from 400 error?

Comment: I suggest you create a blank Suitelet that simply echos back the input parameters, then call it using the expect same parameters that cause the Bad Request 400 Error on the original Suitelet. If you don't get an error, you know it's something to do with the code in your Suitelet. If you DO get the error, perhaps try URL encoding the components param as suggested by Jala below.

Answer (score 0):

Try URL encoding your components param.